# Molecular Level missing items

Tags: fallout-4

I recently started playing Fallout 4 again in hopes of actually finishing the game.
I'm at a point in the game where you need to build the Signal Interceptor. Except the only item I have is the pad itself, nothing else except the robotic workbench in my special inventory. Everything else I need isn't there.
When I place the platform down, the quest doesn't update. When I go to talk to the Railroad [Desdemonda, Tinker Tom, etc.] they only answer with generic responses. Tinker tom allows me to barter with him though.
There is nothing surrounding the platform, nothing but ground beneath it, and there should be enough space. I also have at least 5 platforms now (oops). 
So all the assisting NPC's are unable to help, I only have one note telling me that I need to get certain items for the platform only. Everything else is missing, and I can't power it. Every thread I have seen has not had a fix for me.
[Edit] This is the **Railroad Route**, not the Brotherhood one.

Comment: where did you build it?  did you attach a generator to it?